# Warning while sending template email via sendgrid with '&'

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I'm sending an email with help of the sendgrid api v3 but got the warning/error:

> Content with characters ', " or & may need to be escaped with three brackets
>   {{{ content }}}

in my api json i'm adding an link containing the `&` character:

`{"dynamic_template_data": {"link":"...&..."}}`

in my template i'm using the three brackets `{{{ link }}}`

Everything works as expected - email incl. link are send - but i always got the warning/error.

Do i miss something within the json?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've looked at their code for node.js and as long as any content string has either a (",',&) it will console.warn the message your are seeing.

```
if (/['"&]/.test(value)) {
   console.warn(DYNAMIC_TEMPLATE_CHAR_WARNING);
}
```

See: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/47b6a5cd583cc10544ac19434419bdda5272b107/packages/helpers/classes/mail.js

You can notice the difference with using 2 vs 3 brackets on sendgrid's email template below:
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to turn off this warning, it's very annoying when viewing lots of SendGrid email sends.

Comment: did you found the way to disable this warning?
I'm using `@sendgrid/mail": "^7.2.5` and the warning is still there

Comment: Looks like the only suggestion is to hide all warnings, which i don't think is a good idea:
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/main/docs/use-cases/hide-warnings.md

Comment: @NaturalDevCR yes, hiding all warnings doesn't feel like a good idea. But I checked the code and it looks like this is the only warning _so far_ that can be disabled by that flag. I suggest to hide this warning on specific environments only and still show them in dev and test environments.

Comment: so even if i use the tripple brackets i always will get the warning when the string contains givens characters? hiding all warnings wouldnt be an appropriate way of course!

Answer (score 5):

You can disable warnings setting `hideWarnings` only in you json message not globally:

```
const msg = {
  to: 'recipient@example.org',
  from: 'sender@example.org',
  templateId: 'd-f43daeeaef504760851f727007e0b5d0',
  dynamic_template_data: {
    link: '...&...',
  },
  hideWarnings: true, // now the warning won't be logged
};
```